# Is HTML Markup using for loop in Javascript slower then just normal HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, markup

I'm about to markup very long page and started having a question about HTML markup with javascript.

As i'm using Vue.js, I normally do markup with for loop, but my senior do the markup without any loop(for looping rows), so the length of code is super long and it doesn't seem clean and tight. However, he told me some weird(from my point of view) thing which I don't understand.

What he said is doing markup without javascript for loop is a lot faster in terms of loading. Also, for the each component, writing markup without js for loop, can be more easier to them to display all the features at once, cause doing markup with js might load html slower so it won't sync the page at all.

Currently, I do not believe this theory at all. So i'm wondering the difference between markup with for loop for looping rows(e.g. table rows) and just html markup without any javascript code to make it simpler. Please let me know so that I can learn more about coding.

Comment: Hard to make comparisons of things we can't see. Please provide examples as per [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry my bad. but I found an article about it. no worries at all! Thanks for the reply though! https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dhtml-introduction/

Comment: Looks pretty old when it refers to IE 5 and Netscape

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript to render content to the page adds a layer of complexity to the browser processing engine.

In extremely simplified terms, When the browser gets HTML from the server, it begins parsing the data as HTML from the top-down. (Even script tags need to be parsed as HTML before the script can be run. How else would the browser know it’s a script tag?) In the order of the document, HTML content is rendered to the page and scripts are executed as they are encountered.

When the browser reaches JavaScript Code that changes the DOM, the browser must first execute your code, observe that the DOM was modified and then repaint the area of the screen that was modified.

Remembering that JavaScript code is executed synchronously, if the browser does not encounter code that changes the DOM, it significantly lowers the number of times content needs to be painted to the screen.

Comment: Ah, got the idea of how it works. then does this go to the Vue.js as well? The office website suggest to not to write the markup code like that. and that's the reason why I didn't believe what my senior said...[link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

Comment: I’m not sure what office website you are talking about but if you are only using Vue.is client-side, the logic is the same. If you are using server side rendering, that’s a different story. But this logic pretty much applies to all client side JavaScript (React, JQuery, etc.) all of these libraries funnel down to plain ole JavaScript.

Comment: Also note too that browsers do significant optimization to rendering HTML. For example, Chrome may see a Table tag and not render anything until the ending table so that it only has to do 1 paint.